# Plot Data According to Date in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-analysis, shinydashboard

unlike me i hope you guys are having a good time!. Being a fool shiny guy I Need some guidance.
Okay so i have different columns in my data. for E.g :

> feedback , SUGGESTED_TAG , Language , Country , Date

What I want is:

> that user will be able to select date range through DateRangeInput and
>   can filter out the CategoryData based on the selected date. The output
>   Should be a Histogram or a Bar.

My Code :

```
 library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    data <- read.csv("data Path")
    CategoryData <- data$SUGGESTED_TAG
    LanguageData <- data$Language
DateData <- data$date
DateFilter <- data.frame(CategoryData, date = as.Date(DateData))

ui <- fluidPage(
 plotOutput('myPlot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$myplot <- renderPlot({
                ggplot(DateFilter %>%
                        filter(date >= input$dateRange[1] & 
                                     date <= input$dateRange[2]))
      })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am getting an error:

> Error in tagAssert(body, type = "div", class = "content-wrapper") : 
>     argument "body" is missing, with no default

I don't know am i going in the right path or not,Kindly help how to filter out data with respect to date.Thankyou

Comment: The *input$dateRange* is a character, you need to change it to *Date*.

Comment: Not working with this bro